# Android ACTION_SEND/SEND_MULTIPLE recipients (besides EXTRA_EMAIL)

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to provide support for `ACTION_SEND/SEND_MULTIPLE` inside my application. I've registered the `intent-filter` to allow multimedia/plain text to be supported:

```
<intent-filter
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
<intent-filter>
```

But now I would like to allow for receiving a recipient where the content should be sent to. Is there something equivalent to the `EXTRA_EMAIL` to get a different kind of recipient (like a contact number)?

Imagine some app would like to allow for selecting a contact and share an image/text. Is there a way to set/receive a recipient without using a custom `Intent`?

I'm aware of the [SENDTO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO) action, but it specifically says "Send **a message**...", so I guess it only supports for "sms" and "smsto" schemes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something equivalent to the EXTRA_EMAIL to get a different kind of recipient (like a contact number)?

No, insofar as out of the million-plus apps for Android in use today, approximately none will do that. You are welcome to promote your own custom extra and try to convince developers to support it.

> Imagine some app would like to allow for selecting a contact and share an image/text.

The flow is that they pick the "image/text" first, then choose an app to share it with, then choose the contact(s) inside of that app (assuming the app has the concept of "contacts").

> I'm aware of the SENDTO action, but it specifically says "Send a message...", so I guess it only supports for "sms" and "smsto" schemes.

No, it is also used for `mailto:` (and not `sms` AFAIK).

Comment: Actually, I think SENDTO also applies to `sms:<number>` (see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Messaging)). Still I'm accepting your answer as in this link it seems not to specify anything to receive a recipient as an extra of the Intent. Thanks!